# Ghostscript.net print pdf to network printer windows service

Tags: vb.net, printing, ghostscript

I am using below code to print pdf but it is not working with windows service using network printer.

```
Dim gvi As New GhostscriptVersionInfo(New Version(0, 0, 0), Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "gsdll32.dll"), String.Empty, GhostscriptLicense.GPL)
Dim processor As New Ghostscript.NET.Processor.GhostscriptProcessor(gvi, True)
Dim switches As New List(Of String)()
switches.Add("-empty")
switches.Add("-dPrinted")
switches.Add("-dBATCH")
switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE")
switches.Add("-dNOSAFER")
switches.Add("-dPDFFitPage")
switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1")    
switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2")
switches.Add(Convert.ToString("-sOutputFile=%printer%") & _PrinterName)
switches.Add("-f")
switches.Add(PdfFileName)
processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the networked printer visible to the user on the machine before you try printing ? The way that the mswinpr2 device works, it requires that the printer be visible to the user on the Windows installation its running from.

You cannot print to a printer over the network, unless that printer is mounted on your own system.

Answer (score 1):

Your call seems correct. But for a network printer, you have to use

-sOutputFile="%printer%\\Hostname\Printer"

The hostname (=the machine the printer is pysically connected to) is mandatory here.